# Problema con observables en angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, redux, observable

Hola como podría hacer lo siguiente , tengo un componente ListComponent que sirve de template.
Al final tengo ListComponent1 y ListComponent2 , al cuales se le pasa por input opciones diferentes(tipo de menu si es menuPrincipal , de autentificacion,etc) , en los 2 componentes tengo en el constructor un observable vinculado a un estado redux.

**Constructor**

```
   this.store.select('ListOpciones')
    .subscribe(data=>{
    if(data instanceof Array)
        this.options=data;
    });
```

El problema es el siguiente, cuando el store captura un nuevo dato , este se replica a los 2 componentes en los que fue instanciado , es obvio pues los 2 manejan el mismo observable , sin embargo yo quiero hacer lo siguiente que por ejemplo si cuando me subcribo al store de alguna manera filtrar por tipo , y si por ejemplo el tipo es type:A ,los cambios solo afecten al Componente1 , y si es type:B afecten al Componente2.

Estos haciendolo de esta manera pues , el componente plantilla , representa a un menu de opciones, entre estas tengo a la barra de navegacion , al menu de autentificacion , entre otras cosas , al cual traigo sus opciones mediante la consulta a una api através de un servicio.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el operador `takeWhile` o el operador `filter`.

```html
this.store.select('ListOpciones')
  .takeWhile((e: any) => {
    return e instanceof Array
  }).subscribe(data => {
    //....
  });

this.store.select('ListOpciones')
  .filter((e: any) => {
    return e instanceof Array
  }).subscribe(data => {
    //....
  });
```